# WebSphere Liberty starts multiple singleton EJB instances

Tags: singleton, websphere-liberty, ejb-3.2

I am developing an Enterprise application which is packaged in an ear. The ear consists of one Enterprise Bean application (in a jar), one JAX-RS application (in a war) and one web application (also in a war).

The ear descriptor (application.xml) looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE application PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD J2EE Application 1.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/application_1_3.dtd">
<application>
  <display-name>myapp-ear</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>myapp-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>myapp-rest-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/api</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>myapp-ejb-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</ejb>
  </module>
</application>
```

The EJB application contains a singleton EJB, annotated with @Singleton, @LocalBean and @Startup, which contains a @Schedule method.

I noticed in the log that the server started three instances of the scheduled method simultaneously, and further investigation of the log shows that the bean gets bound three times - one for each application in the ear.

This is in accordance with the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjg.html

BUT: I have a similar application running on the full profile WebSphere server that don't show this behavior. Instead, only one instance exists for the entire Enterprise application.

The WLP server is running 17.0.0.1 with Java version 1.8.0_101

The question is, if this is an error - or am I missing some important setting in WLP?

Answer (score 2):

A class does not determine the unique identity of an EJB. Every EJB has a 3 part unique identifier composed of `<app name>/<module name>/<bean name>`. So, if the same class is packaged in 3 locations, then there will be 3 separate EJB definitions.  Also, you could package the EJB class in a single location, but still have 3 if you identify it as an EJB from 3 separate `ejb-jar.xml` files (assuming the class is in a shared location). This is true of all EJB types, but singleton can make the behavior more obvious.

This behavior is the same for both Liberty and full profile WebSphere. If it appears that the behavior is different on full profile WebSphere, it is likely due to another restriction in packaging.  For example, if you package the singleton class in a WAR or JAR that contains an `ejb-jar.xml` file with `metadata-complete=true` and that file does not define the singleton as an EJB, then it would be ignored. Similarly, if you package the singleton in a WAR module with a version of 2.5 or older, then the WAR module would not support including EJBs, and the Singleton would be ignored.

Comment: I think I may not have described the situation well enough: The singleton bean class is only packaged in one location - inside the EJB module. There is no ejb-jar.xm in any of the projects. All EJBs are annotated. The other modules use the @EJB annotation to inject the session beans as needed - and define no EJBs of their own.

Answer (score 2):

Duh!

The problem turned out to be an incorrectly configured Maven dependency on the EJB archive in pom.xml. What should have been a PROVIDED dependendy was set as a COMPILE dependency - and that caused Maven to package the EJB jar into the two war files.

I changed it in both web applications - and the singleton is now only instantiated once for the entire ear.

In case enybody else is fighting this issue, make sure your dependency is created like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.acme.myapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>myapp-ejb</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <type>ejb</type>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are indeed reading the spec correctly -- singleton beans are enforced to be "one per app per JVM".

Liberty appears to be behaving in compliance with the spec.  The behavior you are observing on WebSphere traditional (aka full profile) is likely due to a different application/EJB setup, or a WebSphere traditional specific extra feature that goes above and beyond the spec by allowing you to limit singleton EJBs across multiple apps.

Comment: The only thing is: the more I think about it, the documented functionality doesn't make much sense when you're packaging an entire application in an ear. You would normally only want one instance - why else package everything together and use a Singleton?